# What is the practical difference between different significance calculators for A/B tests?

Tags: statistical-significance, ab-test, marketing

As background information I could say that we are currently studying A/B testing in University digital marketing class. As I have quite little background in statistics I am little bit wondering about calculating statistical significance for test results. Below are some significance calculators that I have found online.

Kissmetrics - https://www.kissmetrics.com/growth-tools/ab-significance-test/

"Classical way" - https://making.lyst.com/2014/05/10/bayesian-ab-testing/#significance-testing

Optimizely - https://www.optimizely.com/sample-size-calculator/?conversion=11&effect=13&significance=95

There is documentation for these i.e. Kissmetrics says "We calculate Certainty of Improvement using a normal approximation." Optimizely has their "stats engine".

I would like to know what is the purpose for making different testing calculators, wouldn't this lead to confusion if everyone calculates results differently? On what basis should I choose the significance method to get the best results?